# Posting photo on Facebook friends wall IOS SDK will that be affected by Removing the ability to post to friends' timelines via API

Tags: iphone, facebook-ios-sdk

Hello everyone I am posting on my friends wall using this code

`[appDelegate.facebook requestWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/photos",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lld",fbid]]`.

I am posting a photo as my code indicates. I wanted to know if that will be affected as per Facebook Developers Roadmap october 2, 2013.

> Removing the ability to post to friends' timelines via API
>   [Link here](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/#q4_2013)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily find this out by activating the October changes in the developer settings of your app, but i am pretty sure it will be affected.

That´s how you get to the settings: https://developers.facebook.com/apps/[your-app-id]/advanced

> "October 2013 Breaking Changes" > enable

You can always switch back, of course.

Comment: hello thanks for your reply how can we do that by activating the October changes in the developer settings of your app ?

Comment: OK i get this message = "(#200) This app is not allowed to publish to other users' timelines."; So we cannot post anymore right?

Comment: exactly ;) - apps posting on a friends wall are usually considered spam, that´s why it´s not allowed anymore.

Comment: greattt i am using the facebook dialog now.